# How could I turn my function into a promise so I can use await with it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a function that prompts a user for me, however, I need to make it a promise so I can 'await' its completion before continuing in the command.

This is the function located in the `Prompt.js` file

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const ms = require('ms')



    module.exports = async function Prompt(originalMessage, textOrEmbed, {embedColor = 'GREEN', yesNo = false, channel = originalMessage.channel, filterArray = [], time = '5m'} = {}) {


        if (typeof originalMessage !== "object")
            throw new Error(`The provided message was not a message object.`)



        if (typeof textOrEmbed === "object") {
            textOrEmbed = textOrEmbed;
        } else if (typeof textOrEmbed === "string") {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Plus Prompt`)
                .setDescription(textOrEmbed)
                .setImage('https://theprogrammerof.tech/i/plusEmbedBackground.gif')
                .setColor(embedColor)
                .setFooter(`Interactive message prompt: Lasts ${time}  Ran by ${originalMessage.author.username}`, originalMessage.author.avatarURL())
            textOrEmbed = embed;
        } else throw new Error('Provided textOrEmbed option was not a string or embed.')

        channel.send(textOrEmbed)

        let convertedTime = ms(time)

        if (!convertedTime)
            throw new Error('A prompt encountered an error: MS (package) was unable to convert the time you provided. An example time value is: "5m"')

        let filter;

        if (filterArray.length === 0) {
            filter = m => {
                return m.author.id === originalMessage.author.id;
            }
        } else {
            filterArray.push('cancel')
            let errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`The current running prompt received an invalid input`)
                .setDescription(`Proper responses to this prompt are: \`${filterArray.join(', ')}\``)
                .setFooter(`Interactive message prompt: Lasts ${time}  Error  Ran by ${originalMessage.author.username}`, originalMessage.author.avatarURL())
            filter = m => {
                if (m.author.id === originalMessage.author.id && filterArray.includes(m.content.toLowerCase()))
                    return true;
                else if (m.author.id === originalMessage.author.id && !filterArray.includes(m.content.toLowerCase())) {
                    originalMessage.channel.send(errorEmbed)
                }
            }
        }

        channel.awaitMessages(filter, { time: convertedTime, max: 1, errors: ['time']})
            .then(collected => {

                if (!collected) {
                    channel.send('Cancelled Prompt.')
                    return undefined;
                }

                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                    channel.send('Cancelled Prompt')
                    return undefined;
                }


                return collected.first();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                channel.send('Cancelled prompt.')
                return undefined;
            })

    }
```

In the command file, I want the code to wait before sending the message so prompt.content() is available.

`test.js`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
let Prompt = require('../functions/Prompt.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'test',
    enabled: true,
    developer: true,
    usage: 'test',
    cat: 'e',
    run: async (client, message, args, prefixUsed) => {
        try {



            let prompt = await Prompt(message, 'test') //Need this to await to I can prevent the message.channel.send from running before prompt.content is available

            message.channel.send(`Collected ${prompt.content}`)

        } catch (error) {
            message.channel.send(` This command was prevented from executing by a code based issue. Please try again soon.`)
            console.log(error)
        }


    }
};
```

How could I convert the function that I just made into a promise so I can await when the promise resolves?

As a long shot, I tried the code below, but the result had the same outcome.

`Prompt.js(2)`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const ms = require('ms')



module.exports = async function Prompt(originalMessage, textOrEmbed, {embedColor = 'GREEN', yesNo = false, channel = originalMessage.channel, filterArray = [], time = '5m'} = {}) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (typeof originalMessage !== "object")
            throw new Error(`The provided message was not a message object.`)



        if (typeof textOrEmbed === "object") {
            textOrEmbed = textOrEmbed;
        } else if (typeof textOrEmbed === "string") {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Plus Prompt`)
                .setDescription(textOrEmbed)
                .setImage('https://theprogrammerof.tech/i/plusEmbedBackground.gif')
                .setColor(embedColor)
                .setFooter(`Interactive message prompt: Lasts ${time}  Ran by ${originalMessage.author.username}`, originalMessage.author.avatarURL())
            textOrEmbed = embed;
        } else throw new Error('Provided textOrEmbed option was not a string or embed.')

        channel.send(textOrEmbed)

        let convertedTime = ms(time)

        if (!convertedTime)
            throw new Error('A prompt encountered an error: MS (package) was unable to convert the time you provided. An example time value is: "5m"')

        let filter;

        if (filterArray.length === 0) {
            filter = m => {
                return m.author.id === originalMessage.author.id;
            }
        } else {
            filterArray.push('cancel')
            let errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`The current running prompt received an invalid input`)
                .setDescription(`Proper responses to this prompt are: \`${filterArray.join(', ')}\``)
                .setFooter(`Interactive message prompt: Lasts ${time}  Error  Ran by ${originalMessage.author.username}`, originalMessage.author.avatarURL())
            filter = m => {
                if (m.author.id === originalMessage.author.id && filterArray.includes(m.content.toLowerCase()))
                    return true;
                else if (m.author.id === originalMessage.author.id && !filterArray.includes(m.content.toLowerCase())) {
                    originalMessage.channel.send(errorEmbed)
                }
            }
        }

        channel.awaitMessages(filter, { time: convertedTime, max: 1, errors: ['time']})
            .then(collected => {

                if (!collected) {
                    channel.send('Cancelled Prompt.')
                    reject('Cancelled prompt.')
                }

                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                    channel.send('Cancelled Prompt')
                    reject('Cancelled prompt.')
                }


                resolve(collected.first())
            })
            .catch(error => {
                channel.send('Cancelled prompt.')
                reject('Cancelled prompt.')
            })

    })

}
```

If anybody could help that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Would I have to turn it into a class for it to be a promise?

Comment: You don't seem to be returning the promise from the function?

Comment: @plalx I have to do return resolve()? Sorry I'm new with async/await

Comment: You have to return the `new Promise`.

Comment: @plalx Oh, let me try that

Comment: @plalx Could you post that as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the created promise instance (`new Promise(…)`) from `Prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that 'async/await' are syntactic sugar, they are implemented by Promise. 
When you write:

```
try{
  let result = await asyncFunction();
} catch(e) {
}
```

They are equally to:

```
asyncFunction()
  .then(res => {
     res = result;
     ...})
  .catch(e => {
  })
```

Interpreter will do all the works for you.

The problem in here, is that you are mixing Promise and `async/await` using them both. So there are two solution, one is to use `async/await` all the time. Change you `Prompt` function to:

```
module.exports = async function Prompt(........) {
    ....
    // Just directly use await here.
    try{
    var colleected = await channel.awaitMessages(filter, { time: convertedTime, max: 1, errors: ['time']})
    }catch(error){
        channel.send('Cancelled prompt.')
        return undefined;
    }

    if (!collected) {
        channel.send('Cancelled Prompt.')
        return undefined;
    }
    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
        channel.send('Cancelled Prompt')
        return undefined;
    }
    return collected.first();
}
```

I could recommend to use 'async/await' all the time, for it's more clear and simple in most cases.

Another solution is still using Promise with async, since we know that a async function should return a Promise, so we explicitly return a Promise:

```
module.exports = async function Prompt(........) {
    ....
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        channel.awaitMessages(filter, { time: convertedTime, max: 1, errors: ['time']})
        .then(collected => {

            if (!collected) {
                channel.send('Cancelled Prompt.')
                reject('Cancelled prompt.')
            }

            if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                channel.send('Cancelled Prompt')
                reject('Cancelled prompt.')
            }

            resolve(collected.first())
        })
        .catch(error => {
            channel.send('Cancelled prompt.')
            reject('Cancelled prompt.')
        })
    });
}
```

This is similar to your `Prompt.js(2)`. The error in your `Prompt.js(2)` is that you didn't return the Promise you constructed, so whoever calling this function gets nothing.

```
let a = Prompt(); // a should be a Promise, but you didn't returned a Promise, so a will be `undefined`.
```

Hope this help.